# Change loading sequence of style-sheet in GWT/SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-2.8

I am using GWT and SmartGWT in my application. And I want to upgrade application versions as GWT from **2.6.1 to 2.8.2** and SmartGWT from **5.0 to 6.1**. I have successfully migrated it, but facing some UI problems.

The .gwt.xml file looks like below.

```
<module>
    <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt" />
    <inherits name="com.smartclient.theme.enterprise.Enterprise" />
    <inherits name="com.smartgwt.PluginBridgesWidgets" />
    <inherits name="com.myproject.file.Model" />

    <script src="json2.js" />
    <script src="swfobject.js" />

    <stylesheet src="css/home.css" />
    <stylesheet src="css/smartgwt-overrides.css" />
</module>
```

Earlier it was loading style sheets and JS in sequence as GWT/SmartGWT and after that my custom style sheets and JS. But after upgrading it is loading custom CSS and JS first and then GWT/SmartGWT. Because of this the UI is working as earlier.

Anyone have any idea, how to change sequence of loading? I have also tried by changing above sequence of files from .gwt.xml but no worth.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try and load thestyles via code using the StyleInjector.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? Means how to inject? If you have any example for this? And I am totally surprised that how the behaviour changed in the upgrade.

Comment: I have tried elemental 2 but getting error in client side code.

Answer (score 0):

instead of "com.smartgwt.SmartGwt" you can inherit

> com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoTheme

or even

> com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScriptNoTheme

and include all required resources(js and css files) directly to the your html page in the required order.

Comment: Actually I want to use the theme also. In earlier version it was loading in proper sequence but now after upgrade it is loading custom js/css files first and then SmartGwt library js/css files. So why it is behaving like this? 

Currently it is working by adding in html. But customer is not accepting the same.

Comment: Have another an idea for you - extract required theme from smartgwt-skins.jar, apply your changes, rename it, pack as my-smart-gwt-skin.jar and add to the dependencies.